# Why does PCL target ASP.NET Core (and not .NET Core)?

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

As you can see in the image, we have a list of .NET runtimes (right?) and then there's ASP.NET Core which isn't a runtime, but is actually a library / set of libraries.

This is a bit confusing, is there a valid reason for it?

[image: Possible targets for a PCL]

Comment: You are selecting *platforms* here, not runtimes.  UWP, Silverlight and phones are also .NETCore platforms, previous version.  The .NETCore version you are talking about, the open source one, was once named version 5.  But they changed it to version 1 because it was "too confusing".  Thus creating more confusion.  No PCL support is planned, replaced by the .NETStandard approach.  ASP.NET Core made it in the nick of time.  They got it running early, web servers are pretty simple.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I think you have the right answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time on PCL who is dying. When Microsoft added that everything about ASP.NET Core was not fully finalized so it can be confusing and misleading.

Go to learn .NET Standard and you will be freed.

Comment: I'm aware of .NET Standard, and the fact that it replaces PCL, my question was simply why did they put ASP.NET Core on that list (instead of just .NET Core).